# React with Typescript Interface and API calls

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I am pretty new to React with TS or web dev in general. I've been struggling on how to design a interface to match up with the data structure from an api call.

Here's the App.tsx file, and url of the fetch call "https://datausa.io/api/data?drilldowns=Nation&measures=Population"

```
import React from 'react';
import './App.css';

interface OuterModel {
  data: InnerModel[];
  source: object;
}

interface InnerModel {
  idNation: string;
  nation: string;
  idYear: number;
  year: string;
  population: number;
  slugNation: string;
}

function App() {
  const url = "https://datausa.io/api/data?drilldowns=Nation&measures=Population";
  const [data, setData] = React.useState<InnerModel[]>([]);

  function getData(): Promise<InnerModel[]> {
    return fetch(url).then(res => res.json()).then(result => (result as OuterModel).data as InnerModel[]);
  }

  React.useEffect(() => {
    getData().then(item => setData(item));
  }, [])

  return (
  <div>
    <h1>{data.length}</h1>
    <ul>
      {data?.map((item, idx) => <li key={idx}>{item.population}</li>)}
    </ul>
  </div>)
}

export default App;
```

I suppose the fetch call was successful, as h1 showed the count of array. yet the unordered list is always blank. don't know what the problem is. The interface? The way I used hooks? these no errors in console, but it's just not right.

[blank list items](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lLcci.png)

Also, I wonder if I'm doing this the right way. It seems I have to make a call first, say in browser console, to see the structure of returned json, then I can declare an interface for it. I find it a bit awkward. Are there better approaches?

Appreciate any help on this.

Comment: can you check your console for any errors that you might have missed?

Comment: What you are doing to create the interface is correct, but a little manual, there are automated tools like this http://json2ts.com/ that will do it for you.

Comment: @SamridhTuladhar hi man, it's all clear. no errors.

Comment: @SamridhTuladhar wth, oh my.. But really, why it has to be like this? I suppose only the order of keys matters in interface declaration? I replaced keys having space in between with camelCase. They must be exactly the same?

Comment: To answer your first question, no the order of keys in the interface declaration do not matter, you can swap them around, however, it is sensitive to spacing and capital letters, to they have to match, character for character, you can verify this by experimenting different configurations in the tool.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On the response of the API, the "P" of the `population` field is captial, which caused this issue.

One hint that your data has be correctly loaded into memory is already in your screen shot. The value of `data.length` is `7`. Add to the fact that the list has already rendered, but it is empty. ( i.e., the looping logic worked and didn't crash ) which implies that it wasn't able to find the key, and there is where I deduced that there must be some error in your key.

Please use automated tools like https://transform.tools/json-to-typescript to create the interface, doing this manually is correct, but these kind of small errors happens to the best of us.

Comment: I just tried the tool, works great. I thought I can get away from bracket notation and use dot notation exclusively. Now, I realize keys in interface can be like "ID Nation". Thanks man.

Comment: Ideally, it's always better to get away from the bracket notation, because if you might have already noticed using typescript, when you use the dot notation, you get extremely helpful autocompletes. However, that is not true in your case, there is no way to escape that notation here, unfortunately, you'll have to accept it as is, and then convert it to a compatible object.

Comment: thx man, you've been a big help.